# Creating Opengraph metatags for each individual video link on website?

Tags: reactjs, facebook-opengraph, share-open-graph

The site is say https://videosite.com.  Currently each video has its individual link which is generated by the following:

I want to add the OG metatags like thumbnail onto each of these video links like I did for the index.html homepage.

video._id is variable which holds the id of video uploaded to our site.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

```
                 <Button
                      style={{ float: "left" }}
                      variant="contained"
                      color={this.state.copied ? "danger" : "primary"}
                      onClick={() => {
                        "https://videosite.com/#/video/" + video._id));
                        this.setState({ copied: "Copied!" });
                        setTimeout(() => {
                          this.setState({ copied: null });
                        }, 2000);
                      }}
                    >
                      Share {this.state.copied && " - " + this.state.copied}
                    </Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able do this, you need server side rendering (SSR). The crawlers aren't *really* clients, so the server needs to render a specific page for them. Unless you're using server rendering to generate dynamic meta tags, your meta will always be whatever is in index.html. Server rendering is a bit hard to explain how to apply without knowing what you're running and how, but at least it should point you in the right direction.

Some reading material:

- [React Docs on exactly this issue](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/title-and-meta-tags/#generating-dynamic-meta-tags-on-the-server)
- [Simple SSR setup](https://alligator.io/react/server-side-rendering/)